How to Configure EclipseLink (persistance.xml) to Use HikariCP Connection Pool
I have a website that uses a JPA connection pool.
Now I want to configure HikariCP and use its pool with my application.
This is my persistence.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MySQL_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.site.db.jpa.entities.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
    
      <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage" value="mysql"/>
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      
      <!-- PRODUCTION MYSQL 8 -->
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/boilerplatedb?useSSL=false"/>
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser"/>
      <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>

      <!-- eclipse pool -->
      <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.initial" value="5" />
      <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.min" value="8" />
      <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.default.max" value="13" />
      
   

   
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

I've searched and found some posts with this configuration (the Eclipse pool commented above):
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.datasource" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"/>
<property name="jakarta.sql.DataSource" value="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"/>

But it seems to have no effect. I would like to configure HikariCP in the persistence file (without properties map).
thanks
